# Netflix watch history project. Need data source (title & duration of the shows/movies) to match watch history

Tags: analysis, netflix

My project is to find out how much time I spend on netflix.
Downloaded the history containing only Date & show name. (I don't want to request full netflix account history every time I to process it all again).

I am looking for dataset of movies + duration, tv shows with list of episodes and their corresponding duration. CSV format would be awesome
No experience in web scraping...

Thanks!

No clue where to find the data required for my project